# Adding data to children within children in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: week data]

I am able to update data like address and description by doing the following:

```
FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
       String uid = current_user.getUid();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);//.getReference points to root.
        HashMap<String,Object> usermap = new HashMap<>();
        usermap.put("name",name);
        usermap.put("description",description);
        usermap.put("address",address);
        mDatabase.updateChildren(usermap);
```

But how do I add Week? Week has five children which are the days.Within each child, I would like an array of integer or string characters. I tried the same way as above but it does not seem to be working. The above method only works
for key:value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The week is a nested `Map`, so:

```
FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = current_user.getUid();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);//.getReference points to root.
HashMap<String,Object> usermap = new HashMap<>();
usermap.put("name",name);
usermap.put("description",description);
usermap.put("address",address);

Map<String,String> week = new HashMap<>();
week.put("Monday", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
week.put("Tuesday", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
week.put("Wednesday", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
week.put("Thursday", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
week.put("Friday", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");

usermap.put("Week", week);

mDatabase.updateChildren(usermap);
```

Comment: Thank you. I had another question. Later on, I would be required to change the elements of the array in each day. Would this data be easy to retrieve and manipulate?

Comment: "1,1,1,1,1,1,1" is a single string. So, if I were to retrieve it, I would get that string. I would then manipulate that string to something like "1,1,1,1,1,0,1" and push it back. That makes sense I think.

Comment: It all depends on the use-cases of your app. Storing all slots for a day as a single string is fine as long as: 1) you never need to query individual slots, 2) you are OK always updating all slots, instead of an individual slot.

Answer (score 1):

You should crate a POJO model "Week" that would correspond to a desired structure of your node , then create an instance of this object class and push in to `Firebase`

Refer this [tutorial](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-writing-pojos)

Comment: This is useful information. Thanks.This would be better if the data I have is complex but currently It is all mostly strings and integers.

Comment: The data can be primitive but your structure can be really tree-like and complex then you should definitively use a model . Good coding,man!